# Laravel pagination object in javascript

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have an index page where I make the listing of some hospitals with a pagination.

I also have a searchbar where I can write an hospital name and the listing should be updated "in real time" with an AJAX request.

My problem is that I am not able to re-use the laravel pagination object by javascript to create the pagination. And I do not want to manage it by pure javascript/jQuery. At the moment, I'm creating a list of all objects returned. But without pagination (so the list can be huge)

So in my controller I have this function

```
public function index()
{
    $hospitals = Hospital::orderBy('name')->paginate(15);
    return view('admin.hospitals.show', compact('hospitals'));
}
```

In my view (`/admin/hospitals/show.blade.php`), I'm using this to create a pagination (I want to re-use this on ajax response)

```
<ul>
@foreach($tasks as $task)
    <li>{{ $task->name }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
{{ $tasks->links() }}
```

Which give my this result

[image]

When typing in the search bar, this ajax is called

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/admin/hospitals/search/'+ $('#hospital_search').val().trim(),
    success: function (data) 
    {
        if ( data.hospital.length == 0 ) 
        {
            $('#hospital_result').html('<div class="alert alert-warning">No hospitals found</div>');
        }
        else
        {
            //Actual code that give me the listing without pagination
            //Would be nice if I could do something like {{ data.hospital->links() }}
            var html = '<ul>';
            $.each( data.hospital , function( i , hospital ){    
                html += '<li><a href="/admin/hospitals/'+ hospital.id +'"><b>' + hospital.name + '</b></a></li>';});
            html += '</ul>';
            $('#hospital_result').html(html);
        }
    },
    error: function (data) 
    {
        alert('Error:', data);
    }
});
```

And my `search` function

```
public function search($term = null)
{       
    if( !$term )
    {
        $hospital = Hospital::orderBy('name')->get();
    }
    else
    {
        //Get match on name
        $hospital = Hospital::where('name' , 'LIKE' , '%'.$term.'%')
                        ->orderBy('name')
                        ->get(); //Should be replaced by ->paginate(15) when JS will be replaced
    }

    //Return as JSON
    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'hospital' => $hospital]);
}
```

How to use the `->links()` on the `data` object in the ajax response?
Or should I change my logic and load a specific view after ajax request?

Comment: You are also able to use the built in function to paginate any model.

Ex: `$hospital = Hospital::query()->where('name', 'LIKE' "%{$term}%")->paginate($perPage);`

Comment: @KristianHareland That's what I'm using at the moment :-)

Comment: can you show us how you solved this, coz i'm kinda stuck in the same error you had, you can post your own answer... thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`->links()` method generates HTML code, so what you can do is to return it in it's own variable.

```
return response()->json([
    'success' => true,
    'hospital' => $hospital
    'pagination' => $hospital->links()
]);
```

Other way to proceed is to return the table html via JSON and fill a container's content with the response

```
return response()->json([
    'success' => true, 
    'html' => view('hospitals.list')->render()
]);
```

Comment: Passing `$hospital->links()` to javascript did not worked for me. Creating a listing view and passing the rendered view to js was the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like [@Lloople](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2904719/lloople) said, `->links()` method generates HTML code, but to return as JSON I had to cast it to string:

```php
return response()->json([
    'success' => true,
    'hospital' => $hospital
    'pagination' => (string) $hospital->links()
]);
```